# Excel - Retrieve cell name and range name

Tags: excel, range, named

When I look for min/max, not only I would like the result, but also the cell name the result is in as well as it's range name.

e.g. =MAX(B2:C20)

The max is 100 in B6, B6 is part of a named range called Week 1.

Therefore we would like to have a formula that can retrieve:

100, B6, WEEK 1

Please help, I'be been up all night looking for this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I defined the range `B5:B7` to have the Name `WEEK1`:

[image]

and this short *UDF()*:

```
Public Function FindMax(rIN As Range) As String
    Dim mx As Variant, rF As Range, N As Name
    mx = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rIN)
    Set rF = rIN.Find(What:=mx, After:=rIN(1))

    For Each N In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Not Intersect(rF, Range(N.RefersTo)) Is Nothing Then
            lab = N.Name
        End If
    Next N

    FindMax = mx & ", " & rF.Address(0, 0) & ", " & lab
End Function
```

returns:

[image]

You must be carefully to exclude print ranges, etc.

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=FindMax(A1:Z100)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I'm a total newbie, can you kindly tell me how I can place this in/run it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ramon  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Working now! Thank you so much!